# Active class on re-injected html

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

I'm working on a booking web app. I'm trying to add "active" class on my buttons on click. The problem is that theses butons are re-injected when clicked so the JS is not reaching the buttons anymore.

The re-injection works with AJAX and renderview to get the availables dates and times without reloading the page.

I tried to aks Chat GPT for a clue on the situation and here is what I got

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#timeBtn");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  const isButtonClicked = localStorage.getItem(button.id);

  if (isButtonClicked) {
    button.classList.add("active");
  }

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    button.classList.toggle("active");

    const isActive = button.classList.contains("active");
    localStorage.setItem(button.id, isActive ? "clicked" : "");
  });
});
```

Here is my twig

```
<h2 class="text-center">Midi</h2>

    <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center mx-auto mt-3 list-unstyled text-small">
        <div class="js-day" {% for index in time %} data-is-open="{{ index.isclosed ? 'false' : 'true' }}" {% endfor %}></div>


        {% for reservation in availableDateAm %}
            <li class="mx-1 my-1">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary lexend" id="timeBtn">{{ reservation | date("H:i")}}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

    <hr class="mt-5">

    <h2 class="mt-1 text-center">Soir</h2>

    <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center mx-auto mt-3 list-unstyled text-small">
        {% for reservation in availableDatePm %}

            <li class="mx-1 mt-1 my-1">
                <a class="btn btn-dark lexend" id="timeBtn">{{ reservation | date("H:i")}}</a>
            </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

So this solution use local storage to keep the "clicked" information but it doesn't work. The problem seems to come from the re-injection of the buttons when clicked.

Any clues?
Thanks!

Comment: `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#timeBtn");` does not make any sense. An ID is an unique element.

Comment: Oh.. So I can't make a group of buttons with the same individual id ?

Comment: No, use a class rather than ID.

Comment: Don't waste your time asking ChatGPT. It doesn't know how to program any better than you do.

Comment: Ok so I'll use class instead, thanks! Do you guys think it's part of the problem I got ?

Comment: Yes in part, the other is your selector should be delegated from the container if the HTML is being injected after load. EG: `body.onClick(function(event) { return event.target.classList.contains('do-thing') ? dothing() : true;  })` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation